# This sample delete code wont delete items from database

Tags: php, mysqli

This a sample delete code I created to delete entries MySQL database. When I execute this code, Successful message displays but entries wont delete from the database. Records are kept track the primary key in the 'events' table 'id'

```
<?php
    require 'dbconnect.php';
    session_start();
    $id=$_SESSION['id'];
    $id = "0";

    if ( !empty($_GET['id'])) {
        $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
    }

    if ( !empty($_POST)) {
        // keep track post values
        $id = $_POST['id'];

        // delete data


        $sql="DELETE * FROM events WHERE events.id='$id'"; //mysqli query
        $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql); //connection string and mysqli query variable


    if($result==true)
            {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('successfully DELETED!')</script>"; // javascript message for Successful delete
    echo "<script>setTimeout(\"location.href = 'list_events.php';\",15);</script>"; // return page

            }
            else
            {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('failed to DELETE RETRY!')</script>"; //failed to delete message
    echo "<script>setTimeout(\"location.href = 'list_events.php';\",15);</script>"; //return page
            }
            header("Location: list_events.php"); // header page

        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Try `DELETE FROM` instead of `DELETE * FROM`

Comment: are you sure the `id` you are setting exists in the table? a `DELETE` statement will not return `false` if the element does not exist, i believe..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DELETE FROM instead of DELETE * FROM and you can use the following commands for more security:

```
$sql="DELETE FROM events WHERE events.id=?"; 
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('d',$id);
/* execute prepared statement */
$result = $stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
$sql="DELETE FROM events WHERE events.id='{$id}'"; //mysqli query
```

Just to be safe.
Do check if you are getting some value in $id and it also exist in database.